# I can't format data properly into Tensorflow. What am I missing here?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am having a hard time understanding this error.  I am following the Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) using the MNIST dataset, but adapting it to use on my own images.

```
train_data, eval_data = tf.stack(train_data), tf.stack(eval_data)
train_labels, eval_labels = np.asarray(train_labels), np.asarray(eval_labels)

train_data = tf.reshape(train_data, [-1, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 4])
eval_data = tf.reshape(eval_data, [-1, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 4])
```

train_data and eval_data are a list of images returned from

```
from matplotlib import image as mpimg
mpimg.imread(DIR_TO_IMAGE)
```

and train_labels and eval_labels are simply a list of numbers containing the class value for the corresponding images.  (i.e., [1,2,3,4,....,16]).

However when I run the program I am encountering this error

> ValueError: Length of tensors in x and y is mismatched. All elements in x and y must have the same length.
>   Shapes in x: {'x': TensorShape([Dimension(7), Dimension(400), Dimension(400), Dimension(4)]), '**target_key**': (7,)}
>   Shape for y: (7,)

What have I done wrong here? Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see where the x and y is in your code. Methinks you just hide them? : )?